Alternative to Google Service Account for Personal Gmail?
We're using a personal gmail account to manage our Google Ads and therefore create the Oauth access to send LSA data. Is there anyway to provide access to a vendor using the personal gmail as an alternative to the service account method?
Since it's a personal gmail my understanding is a service account won't work...
Tried creating a service account, trying to avoid having to create a g suite just for this
